# Get index of element in C++ map

Tags: c++, dictionary, indexing, std

I have a `std::map` called `myMap` in my C++ application, and I want to get an element using either `myMap.find(key)` or `myMap[key]`. However, I would also like to get the index of that element in the map.

```
std::map<string, int> myMap;
// Populate myMap with a bunch of items...
myElement = myMap["myKey"];
// Now I need to get the index of myElement in myMap
```

Is there a clean way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: map's don't have an index, but an iterator.

Comment: I don't think it's really want you meant, but what you are *asking* for is `std::distance(std::begin(myMap), myMap.find("myKey"))`.

Comment: I am curious: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Also, `find[]`? `find()`, or `[]`? They are different.

Comment: @BoBTFish oops... fixed now

Comment: What do you mean with `index`?

Comment: @JosuéMolina to implement a simple substitution cipher. So, if I can find out the position of 'a' in the map then I can figure out which letter to replace it with.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I mean the position of the element in the map.

Comment: @SZH: What is the *position* of the element in the map? the 'key'? the number in the sorted sequence?

Comment: @SZH: the most obvious concept in my mind for implementing a substitution cipher would be to map the "before" characters to "after characters, which doesn't need an index.  Why do you need an index?

Comment: Have you considered using a `std::map<char, char>` instead?

Comment: You can do this : `for ( int i = 0; auto const& [key, value] : someMap ) {i++;}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `std::map` doesn't really have an index, instead it has an iterator for a key / value pair.  This is similar to an index in that it represents a position of sorts in the collection but it is not numeric.  To get the iterator of a key / value pair use the `find` method

```
std::map<string, int>::iterator it = myMap.find("myKey");
```

Answer (score 91):

I came here seeking for this answer but i found this
distance function takes 2 iterators and returns an index

```
cout << distance(mymap.begin(),mymap.find("198765432"));
```

hope this helps :D

Comment: This is really the answer to the question.

Comment: Doesn't it have `O(N)` complexity?

Comment: "Linear. However, if `InputIt` additionally meets the requirements of RandomAccessIterator, complexity is constant."
See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Comment: @willir and @MartinR. Anyways `map::find` has O(logN), even if the `std::distance` has a constant time complexity.

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time when you are working with indices and maps, it usually means that your map is fixed after some insertions. If this assumption holds true for your use case, you can use my answer.

If your map is already fixed (you wouldn't add/delete any key afterward), and you want to find an index of a key, just create a new map that maps from key to index.

```cpp
std::map<string, int> key2index; // you can use unordered_map for it to be faster
int i = 0;
for (pair<K, V> entry : yourMap) {
    key2index[entry.first] = i++;
}
```

From this `key2index` map you can query the key as often as you can. Just call `key2index['YourKey']` to get your index.

The benefit of this method over `distance` function is access time complexity. It's `O(1)` and very fast if you do query often.

**Extra Section**

If you want to do the opposite, you want to access key from index then do the following.

Create an array or vector that stores keys of your entire map. Then you can access the key by specifying the index.

```
vector<int> keys;
for (pair<K,V> entry : yourMap) {
    keys.push_back(entry.first);
}
```

To access an index `i` of your map, use `yourMap[keys[i]]`. This is also `O(1)` and significantly faster because it's using only an array/vector, not a map.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
int k = distance(mymap.begin(), mymap.find(mykey));
```

It will give you the index of the key element.

Answer (score 2):

Well - map is keeping the key and the data as a pair 
so you can extract key by dereferecing the map's iterator into pair or directly into pair's first element.

```
std::map<string, int> myMap;
std::map<string, int>::iterator it;

for(it=myMap.begin();it!=myMap.end();it++)
{
    std::cout<<it->first<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an index in a map. Maps are not stored (not necessarly, at least; and indeed they are not in most implementations) as a sequence of "pairs".

Regardless of the implementation, however, std::map does not model a container having an index.

Depending on what you are asking this question for, the "index" can be an iterator (as suggested by others) or the key itself.

However, it sounds strange you asked this question. If you could give us a bit more details we would probably be able to point you to a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I think you edited your second sentence to much; it's the opposite of true.

Comment: std::map is always sorted. Just want to correct the statement in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The semantic of a map does not include indexes. To understand that, you can note that Maps are typically implemented as trees. Therefore, elements in it do not have an index (try to define an index in a natural way for a tree).

Answer (score 0):

Map is a key-value data structure which internally data in a tree structure. There are O(n) solution stated above.
" distance(mymap.begin(),mymap.find("198765432")) " will not bring you the correct answer.
For your requirement, you have to build your own segment tree type data structure for O log(n) competitive operations.

Answer (score 0):

A use case: if you want to know how many items are smaller or equal as you progress on a vector. Constraint : i < = j, how many v[i]'s are smaller or equal to v[j]). let's insert it into a map or set.

```
vector<int> v={1, 4, 2, 3};
set<int> s;
s = {1}; // 1's position is 1 (one based)
s = {1,4}; //4's positon is 2
s = {1, 2, 4} ;//2's position is 2
s = {1 , 2, 3, 4}; //3's positon is 3
```

it seems std:distance would need a O(n) time.
I could achieve same affect using set.lower_bound() and counting backward till set.begin(). Does anyone have a better solution than requiring O(n) , perhaps using additional data structures?

OK, on a second thought here is a solution to store index (1 based) for this specific problem. However it may not solve the problem for get the correct index of items in the finished map.

```
vector<int> arr={1 , 1 , 2, 4, 2};
multimap<int, int> track; 
for(auto a:arr)
{
    auto it = track.insert(make_pair(a, 1)); //first item is 1
    if(it!=track.begin())
    {
        --it;
        int prev=it->second;
        it++;
        it->second+=prev;
    }  
    cout<<a<<','<<it->second-1<<endl;     
}
```